# Exception while retrieving Salat Object with Subclass

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, specs2, salat

I have an object with has an subclass as attribute:

```
case class UpgradeInfo(
    @EnumAs upgradeType: UpgradeType.Value,
    @EnumAs timeUnit: TimeUnit.Value,
    timeQuantity: Int,
    start: Date,
    end: Date)

case class Upgrade(
    @Key("_id") id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
    adId: ObjectId,
    upgradeInfo: UpgradeInfo,
    price: Double)
```

Creating and updating the object works fine, but when I try to retrieve the Upgrade object with this code (should retrieve all upgrade objects):

```
UpgradeDAO.find(MongoDBObject()).toList
```

I get following exception:

```
[error]     Exception: class models.entities.Upgrade requires value for 'upgradeInfo' (Grater.scala:402)
[error] com.novus.salat.DefaultArg.safeValue$lzycompute(Grater.scala:406)
[error] com.novus.salat.DefaultArg.safeValue(Grater.scala:402)
[error] com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater.safeDefault(Grater.scala:363)
[error] com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Grater.scala:262)
[error] com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Grater.scala:262)
[error] com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater$$anonfun$5.apply(Grater.scala:262)
[error] com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater$$anonfun$5.apply(Grater.scala:247)
[error] com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater.asObject(Grater.scala:247)
[error] com.novus.salat.dao.SalatMongoCursorBase$class.next(SalatMongoCursor.scala:45)
[error] com.novus.salat.dao.SalatMongoCursor.next(SalatMongoCursor.scala:151)
[error] com.novus.salat.dao.SalatMongoCursor.foreach(SalatMongoCursor.scala:151)
[error] com.novus.salat.dao.SalatMongoCursor.to(SalatMongoCursor.scala:151)
[error] com.novus.salat.dao.SalatMongoCursor.toList(SalatMongoCursor.scala:151)
[error] models.entities.UpgradeDAO$.find(Upgrade.scala:47)
[error] models.UpgradeSpecs$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$28$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(UpgradeSpecs.scala:129)
[error] models.UpgradeSpecs$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$28$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(UpgradeSpecs.scala:128)
[error] play.api.test.Helpers$.running(Helpers.scala:40)
[error] models.UpgradeSpecs$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(UpgradeSpecs.scala:128)
[error] models.UpgradeSpecs$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(UpgradeSpecs.scala:128)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a document in your mongo collection which is missing the value for `upgradeInfo`.

You have a couple of options here:

1. provide a default argument for `upgradeInfo`
2. change the type of `upgradeInfo` to `Option[UpgradeInfo]` and supply a default value of `None`
3. search your mongo collection to find the bad document(s) and remove or manually repair the documents which are missing `upgradeInfo`